# MySQLi & PHP - Something obvious that I can't see

Tags: php

Can someone please help me with this? It's driving me mad. I can't see what's wrong...

```
$stmt_query = "SELECT aboutme_profile FROM ProfilesAboutMe WHERE aboutme_profile = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql_connect, $stmt_query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $return_profile_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); // Always shows 0
echo $return_profile_id; // Shows correct value

if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0)
{
    $stmt_query = "INSERT INTO ProfilesAboutMe (aboutme_profile, aboutme_text) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql_connect, $stmt_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $return_profile_id, $aboutme);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Both queries are okay as I've copied and pasted them into phpMyAdmin and they run just fine when binding the params manually.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in

```
SELECT aboutme_profile FROM ProfilesAboutMe WHERE aboutme_profile = 123456789 LIMIT 1
```

When I edit the query in PHP to hard code an aboutme_profile value, I get 0 results. I run the same query in MySQL and get 1 result.

Comment: What do you mean by `binding the params manually` you mean passing the variables in the query works?

Comment: @Jeff I have another statement directly above this one which works just fine, in fact I copied and pasted the code and changed the query. Just don't get it :/

Comment: @chris85 I change ? to 123456789, which returns results in MySQL

Comment: Okay, what about if you put in `$return_profile_id`, still getting results?

Comment: @chris85 When I edit the query in PHP to hard code a aboutme_profile value, I get 0 results. I run the same query in MySQL and get 1 result. $return_profile_id is set to 123456789 as expected

Comment: @Jeff I don't believe that is correct. The query directly above this one is working just find otherwise $return_profile_id would be blank, which it's not. Plus, if I var_dump($sql_connect) at the start of this query, I can see it's connected just fine. And by the way mysqli_connect_errno() = 0

Comment: sorry, my fault. I misread the error to be in mysqli_prepare. I take it all back.

Comment: where is `$aboutme` set?

Comment: and by the way `$return_profile_id` is never 'set' in the code you're showing.

Comment: @Jeff I can confirm $aboutme is set just about the code, that's not the issue. The $return_profile_id is set from the query above this one, ironically, which was copied and pasted to form this.

Comment: Like I said the first query works so I know the DB and connection are fine, and the query is fine because it runs in MySQL. I have just copied and pasted the working code again to see what happens and it runs the first time and errors on the second run. I suspect this is a classic case of being "out of sync".

Comment: Yes, as suspected! **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.**. Time to crack open a beer and relax! Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could make an (well explained) answer out of that!

Comment: Wasn't allowed to answer me own question